# how to make relation between two foreign key values of two tables in Yii

Tags: yii, relation

I have the database just like this

```
==== cis_policy_registration====
id
policy_id
email_id
policy_start_date


==== cis_policy_family_details===
id
policy_id
is_main_applicant
firstname
lastname
gender
```

Now how to make the relation  between models with the policy_id (both tables),
I want to take firstname and lastname in registration model and check is main applicant

that must list in CGridView

who can solve this problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between these two tables should be handled from the "main" model (Policy), so in Policy model class you should have:

```
'policy_reg' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'PolicyRegistration', 'policy_id'),
'policy_details' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'PolicyDetails', 'policy_id'),
```

And then:

```
$policy = Policy::model()->with(array('policy_details'))->findByPk($pk);
$policy->policy_details->is_main_applicant;
...
```

And in CGridView you can print the relational value like this (after sending CActiveDataProvider object from Policy model):

```
'policy_details.firstname'
```

or

```
array(
    'name'=>'Firstname',
    'value'=>'$data->policy_details->firstname',
),
```

Comment: how to get $pk   or where  [$policy = Policy::model()->with(array('policy_details'))->findByPk($pk);]  this code must paste

Comment: $pk is your Primary Key (id) for the Policy model.